# BottomNavigationView together with a FrameLayout - clicking on an icon doesn't change the state. The question works

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

everyone. I have a BottomnNavigationsBar and a FrameLayout inside my activity_main.xml file. In the frame I display a ViewPager within a Fragment. The navigation contains 3 elements. If I click on one, the clicked status does not change. The respective fragment is displayed correctly, but the icon does not change in color and size.
What am I doing wrong or what do I have to change?

Here is my MainActivity:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(viewBinding.root)
    setFragementTo(HomeFragment.newInstance("",""))

    viewBinding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener{
        when(it.itemId)
        {
            R.id.home ->{
                setFragementTo(HomeFragment.newInstance("",""))
            }
            R.id.neu ->{
                setFragementTo(NewFragment.newInstance("",""))

            }
            R.id.settings ->{
                setFragementTo(FilterFragment.newInstance("",""))
                
            }
        }

        false
    }
 }



private fun setFragementTo(fragment: Fragment) {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.myFrameInMain,fragment).commit()
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/myFrameInMain"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></FrameLayout>



<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav_style"
   app:itemRippleColor="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/item_bottom_nav"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/item_bottom_nav"
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here I click on the middle icon in the navigation. The fragment appears correctly, but the icon in the navigation does not

[image]

And here the filter icon:
[image]

Comment: Instead of setOnItemSelectedListener did you try setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener

Comment: yes same problem

Answer (score -1):

I think I got it. I had to change the parameter from false to true in the setOnItemSelectedListener method